# Using Linq Grouping how to I order by specific Group then remaining Groups descending

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, grouping

This Code is **working example** of the content of a select case statement. It is in response to a link button click who's ID is passed in via Session variable. The link buttons represent High(3) Medium(2) and Low(1) Risk categories.

The logic here is; if you select Medium(2) it's related rows (riskCategory =2) are displayed first then the remaining rows ( risk category ) are listed descending so 3 then 2 then 0)

As I said my ugly implementation of the Linq Concat function to accomplish my goal does produce correct results, but it also showcases my need to spend more weekends reviewing and creating better intricate samples than the simple 101 Link Samples tutorial project provides.

There must be a more elegant way to group and order by while allowing for the groups to be ordered representing the selected group first, with remaining groups descending.  Again Select Group 1 LowRiskCategory, I'll have to display LowRiskCategory first (1)  then 3, 2, &  0  respectively in the sorted results set.

```
var midQuery = enumerableVersionTable.Where(x => x["RiskCategory"].Equals(intRiskCategoryEnum));                                    
midQuery.OrderByDescending(v => v["DateOfService"]);
midQuery.OrderBy(v => v["Reviewed"]);

var midQueryZero = enumerableVersionTable.Where(x => x["RiskCategory"].Equals(0));
midQueryZero.OrderByDescending(v => v["DateOfService"]);
midQueryZero.OrderBy(v => v["Reviewed"]);

var midQueryOne = enumerableVersionTable.Where(x => x["RiskCategory"].Equals(1));
midQueryOne.OrderByDescending(v => v["DateOfService"]);
midQueryOne.OrderBy(v => v["Reviewed"]);

var midQueryThree = enumerableVersionTable.Where(x => x["RiskCategory"].Equals(3));
midQueryThree.OrderByDescending(v => v["DateOfService"]);
midQueryThree.OrderBy(v => v["Reviewed"]);

var querySummation = midQuery.Concat(midQueryThree);
querySummation = querySummation.Concat(midQueryOne);
querySummation = querySummation.Concat(midQueryZero);
dtQueryResults = querySummation.CopyToDataTable()
```

Just the sight of those hardcoded numeral values after the translated enum value for case 2:
makes me wana hurl. Theres gotta be more elegant way to do the groups. Order by a specific group. and of course apply all my other odd sorting, as you see date of service and reviewed.

Lastly if you going to AGAIN vote down
at least explain why please thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dtQueryResults = yourData
            .OrderByDescending(v => v["RiskCategory"] == intRiskCategoryEnum)//true for ==2 goes first, false goes then
            .ThenBy(v => v["RiskCategory"]) //the rest is sorted normally
            .ThenBy(v => v["Reviewed"]) //inside the groups, the rest of your sorts is used
            .ThenByDescending(v => v["DateOfService"]);
```

Comment: Your OrderByDescending is attempting to compare an Object to an integer.  And if I understand what you've presented your implying that there's a block of this in every case. Also this code addresses only the selected case you haven't even appended the remaining groups/cases to your query results, for even this one specific case of the switch statement...  My proposed albeit UGLY solution addresses one case completely  case 2:  button 2 selected  Mid category.   I'll have to have this ugliness (rearranged) in at least three cases. Your answer doesn't even address the single case

Comment: I dont know the signature of your data, I guess the == has to be replaced by an Equals call.

There is no more need to appending remaining groups, because there is no filtering in the query I proposed. If you try to evaluate it instead of your code example, you will see, that all data is present and is primarily sorted by RiskCategory in the order:2,0,1,3.

Comment: Tested , replaced comparison as recommended,   amazed that order by  descending specific "RiskCategory" then order by generic "RiskCategory"  works like that. Wondering of the descending will matter at all since we're specifying the first "RiskCategory" Thank you very much. I will be reviewing all the 101 LinQ samples project again this weekend and AGAIN making my own reference solution with handy snippets. Thank you !!  This 9 lines can successfully replace my 15 lines again in each case statement ...

Comment: descending does make a difference  I don't understand why though

Comment: I recommend to read something about IOrderedQueryable<T> Interface and the difference between ThenBy/ThenByDescending and OrderBy/OrderByDescending

Answer (score 0):

Just change the lambda which you have used for the OrderBy. you are not limited to picking up just one field. I'd use a tertiary expression to select what to sort on based on what is selected.